# AngularJS: What is 'this' when AngularJS controller is a member function of a class?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I use a member function of a class to be AngularJS controller:
Note: the code below is compiled from some TypeScript code.

```
function Clazz(x) {

   this.Member = x;

   this.Func= function ($scope) {          
      $scope.message = '' + this.Member;   // this.Member is undefined
   }
} 


app.controller('TaxCtrl',  new Clazz('Hello').Func  );
```

The `Func` is called when the I switch to the `TaxCtrl`, but the `this` seems not to be the instance of `Clazz` because `this.Member` is always undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `Func` is a member of the `Clazz` instance then this will work. When angular constructs the function as an object is is creating a new object where `this` is referencing the instance of `Func`.

Here is a jsbin example:

http://jsbin.com/rocopiwila/edit?js,console

If you are trying to share properties down to controllers use services and injectables instead.

Comment: So angular `new` the controller inside? I thought it just called the controller function.

Comment: I'm assuming so. You can use `this` in a function to set properties to the constructed controller. You actually don't need scope unless you are using events or manually calling `$apply` or `$digest`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function Clazz(x) {

   this.Member = x;
   self = this;

   this.Func= function ($scope) {          
      $scope.message = '' + self.Member;   
   }
} 


app.controller('TaxCtrl',  new Clazz('Hello').Func  );
```

Comment: Thanks. But my code is compiled from some Typescript code, so I cannot add the `self` out of `Func`